# Are there any pitfalls in writing WPF apps with IronRuby?

Tags: .net, wpf, ruby, mvvm, ironruby

Using IronRuby/IronPython, you should technically be able to do anything you could do in C#/VB .Net.  I'm curious if there is anything that would keep a serious rubyist from writing a WPF app for Windows/Silverlight if they were inclined.  A post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458332/are-ironpython-or-ironruby-well-suited-for-the-mvvm-pattern-in-wpf-silverlight) mentions problems with Silverlight and bindings, but I think there are ways around that.

I'm working on an [MVVM library](http://nomvvm.codeplex.com/) that makes heavy use of dynamic, and I wanted to try it out with some examples using dynamic languages.

Comment: I don't really have Windows experience, but this looks like writing WPF apps in IronRuby is quite feasible: http://www.infoq.com/articles/ironruby-wpf

Comment: Great example of WPF with ruby.  I think usage of my library should help clean it up significantly, though.

Comment: Well, I just gave it a whirl and the visual studio experience isn't quite there with WPF.  There isn't a project template and I'm not seeing equivalent to what I'd expect for C#.  I will give the Silverlight template a whirl though.

Comment: As I said, I've always been more of a Unix guy, so can't comment much on that, but I hope the article was at least somewhat useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IronRuby doesn't include a WPF project template, and the link above is a workaround to force WPF to work, but it is not optimal.  There isn't an option to setup App.xaml/App.xaml.cs (oops I mean App.xaml.rb), etc.  This is the location where WPF application startup is performed, and it is needed for setting up Application-level static resources, etc.

IronPython, however, has a WPF project template and seems to set up WPF projects appropriately.

IronRuby seems a little behind IronPython for now (just IMO), so I think I'm going to stick with testing my MVVM framework for WPF in IronPython for now.